# How to create gameplays with facecam?

Tags: screencast

I would like to know how to create gameplays with facecam?
What is the free program I could use?
And is there any tutorial on how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on your graphics card, I would use OBS.
It's free, and it works on any NVIDIA and INTEL graphics card.
AMD/ATI is not supported sadly.

Comment: OBS? where to download it? is there any tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: Just google OBS.